# Eliminate this unneeded copy in list.extend

Tags: python, optimization

Given two normal python lists, `newlist` and `oldlist`, with an integer `index` < `len(oldlist)`, I'd like to perform the following operation:

```
newlist.extend(oldlist[index:])
```

but without creating the intermediate list `oldlist[index:]`, or equivalently,

```
newlist.extend(oldlist[i] for i in xrange(index, len(oldlist)))
```

without the overhead of a generator. Is that possible without using C?

Edit: This question derived from some looking at the  c implementation of some list operations, in particular for `list.extend()`, when the interpreter determines that it can guess the size of the tail being added to the list, it allocates that full size to the head list and copies the elements as they are generated; for other cases, it allocates a few elements at a time (about eight, if memory serves), and copies elements in a few at a time.

The specific cases when it does the full allocation seemed to be for python lists, and a few other types that have a `__len__`.  As far as I can tell, there's no built in type of 'list view' that would satisfy those requirements.

Comment: Do you have benchmarks which show that the generator or the slice has significant overhead?

Comment: `islice` might have a lower overhead. still a generator though.

Comment: Generator shouldn't have a noticeable overhead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't guess, measure

```
create = """
oldlist = range(5000)
newlist = range(5000, 10000)
index = 500
"""
tests = [
    "newlist.extend(oldlist[index:])",
    "newlist.extend(oldlist[i] for i in xrange(index, len(oldlist)))",
    "newlist.extend(islice(oldlist, index, None))",
    """\
while index < len(oldlist):
   newlist.append(oldlist[index])
   index+=1""",
]

import timeit
for test in tests:
    t = timeit.Timer(create + test, setup='from itertools import islice')
    print test, min(t.repeat(number=100000))
```

---

```
newlist.extend(oldlist[index:]) 17.2596559525
newlist.extend(oldlist[i] for i in xrange(index, len(oldlist))) 53.5918159485
newlist.extend(islice(oldlist, index, None)) 19.6523411274
while index < len(oldlist):
   newlist.append(oldlist[index])
   index+=1 123.556715012
```

Comment: The last one is wrong! After the first run, the while loop is never executed

Comment: ... clearly demonstrating you need to be careful what you measure, too :P  Now it shows what I'd expect.

Comment: **I can't reproduce your result for the 4th option** I get it at about twice the time of the second option. I have done two tests, one with your numbers (items extended = 1000 - 500) another with oldlist=range(5000) (items extended = 5000 - 500). Are you sure it's 0.122 usecs, not 122 usecs?

Comment: Well, although this doesn't actually answer my question, which seems to be "No", the extra copy doesn't actually seem to be very expensive (add a `"newlist.extend(oldlist)"` as a control case to see).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be:

```
while index < len(oldlist):
    newlist.append(oldlist[index])
    index += 1
```

But be wary of premature optimization, I've never run into a situation in which the loss of readability in this solution would be worth it.  And, of course, benchmark all options to make sure that the solution you *think* is faster, actually is.

Answer (score 0):

```
appendnew = newlist.append
try:
    while 1:
        appendnew(oldlist[index])
        index += 1
except IndexError:
    pass
```

or, slightly less bogglingly:

```
appendnew = newlist.append
for i in xrange(index, len(oldlist)):
    appendnew(oldlist[i])
```

Comment: your seconds method uses a generator (Which the author wants to avoid). Plus it's missing a `)`

Comment: @Wally: s/seconds/second/ ... now we're even in the typo stakes; the OP wanted FOR NO GOOD REASON to avoid a generator that produced the ELEMENTS of the extension, not the INDICES.

Answer (score 0):

**Some clues on better benchmarking**

Measure the overhead and subtract it off.

Put the code inside a function or method (simulates reality; helps ensure no nasty effects from having variables as global).

```
from itertools import islice
def f0(newlist, oldlist, index):
    pass
def f1(newlist, oldlist, index):
    newlist.extend(oldlist[index:])
def f2(newlist, oldlist, index):
    newlist.extend(oldlist[i] for i in xrange(index, len(oldlist)))
def f3(newlist, oldlist, index):
    newlist.extend(islice(oldlist, index, None))
def f4(newlist, oldlist, index):
    while index < len(oldlist):
        newlist.append(oldlist[index])
        index += 1


>python -mtimeit -s"old=range(1000);new=range(5000,10000);ix=500;import xtnd"; "xtnd.f4(new,old,ix)"
```

If the code being benchmarked has a variable N (in this case N = len(oldlist) - index), benchmark with more than one value of N. If you expect O(N) behaviour, O(1) results should be a cause for investigation.

Also compare results across pairs of candidates with reasonable expectations --- wild variations should be investigated; they could be caused by experimental error.

Comment: This benchmark uses the same list for all iterations and keeps adding to the same list. So first iterations have a smaller list than latter ones. Not sure if that's what you intended to benchmark.